# Accessing URL from AVPlayer object?

Tags: ios, avplayer

Is there a way to access the URL from an AVPlayer object that has been initialized with a URL, as in:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.example.org/audio"];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: url];
```

Comment: The `AVPlayer` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) don't appear to give a way to grab the URL. You can try to see if it responds to `valueForKey:` with various permutations of `@"URL"`, but I doubt it will be exposed.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

An `AVPlayer` plays an `AVPlayerItem`. `AVPlayerItem`s are backed by objects of the class `AVAsset`. When you use the `playerWithURL:` method of `AVPlayer` it automatically creates the `AVPlayerItem` backed by an asset that is a subclass of `AVAsset` named `AVURLAsset`. `AVURLAsset` has a `URL` property.

So, yes, in the case you provided you can get the `NSURL` of the currently playing item fairly easily. Here's an example function of how to do this:

```
-(NSURL *)urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player{
    // get current asset
    AVAsset *currentPlayerAsset = player.currentItem.asset;
    // make sure the current asset is an AVURLAsset
    if (![currentPlayerAsset isKindOfClass:AVURLAsset.class]) return nil;
    // return the NSURL
    return [(AVURLAsset *)currentPlayerAsset URL];
}
```

Not a swift expert, but it seems it can be done in swift more briefly.

```
func urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer(player : AVPlayer) -> URL? {
    return ((player.currentItem?.asset) as? AVURLAsset)?.url
}
```

Comment: May want to check that `player.currentItem` is not `nil` also in the case of an empty init

Comment: @jocull You certainly could check for `nil` so as to not waste time sending messages to `nil`. But the beauty of objective-c is that this code is completely safe. In objective-c sending a message to `nil` doesn't crash and simply returns a 'nil` or `0` or `NO`(depending on return type, they're all the same anyway). So the only check required is the the if statement I included to make sure the asset is a url-asset because if it wasn't then it wouldn't respond to the `-URL` selector, and would crash.

Comment: I forget what was happening when I wrote this, but if `player.currentItem` is nil then trying to use `player.currentItem.asset` will crash. That's the only thing to really watch out for.

Answer (score 18):

#### Oneliner swift 4.1

```
let url: URL? = (player?.currentItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset)?.url
```

Answer (score 13):

Solution for Swift 3

```
func getVideoUrl() -> URL? {
    let asset = self.player?.currentItem?.asset
    if asset == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
        return urlAsset.url
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 6):

AVPlayerItem extension base on [@eonist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50428861/9048325) answer.

```
extension AVPlayerItem {
    var url: URL? {
        return (asset as? AVURLAsset)?.url
    }
}
```