# How to get current ts file from avplayer

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem, nsurlprotocol

I'm trying to figure out how to get current ts file from the avplayer.
I tried subclassing NSURLProtocol, but that doesn't show the url from the avplayeritem.

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036204/2975371

Comment: @Danieboy same comment as I wrote to the answer below. This gives you the .m3u8 and not the TS.