# Get redirected URL in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

Sometimes when playing a video in AVPlayer, the original URL (the one passed to `AVPlayer(url:)` or to `AVURLAsset(url:)`) redirects to the actual URL.

For example:
`https://example.com/video/latest.m3u8`
=>
`https://example.com/video/123456.m3u8`

AVPlayer automatically follows the redirect, which is great; but how can I get the final URL?

I checked, and the URL inside `AVPlayer.currentItem.asset` is the **original** one.

Comment: see this for help : [Accessing URL from AVPlayer object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035501/accessing-url-from-avplayer-object)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the answers there suggest exactly what I said **doesn't** work: they look at the URL inside AVPlayer.currentItem.asset.

Comment: Made it clearer what doesn't work.